# 2014 Chevy Spark issues with excessive coolant usage

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, cooling-system, cooling

Why must I add coolant every few days to my 2014 Chevy Spark, It seems excessive, but I haven't noticed any fluid on the ground?()

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you having any issues with your cooling system such as overheating, or your heat not functioning?

Comment: It's possible that you have a very slow leak where the coolant is dribbling onto something hot and evaporating.  Do you smell the tell-tale sickly sweet odor of antifreeze?  Or... your coolant was low to begin with - perhaps with an air pocket - and its reaching "full" slowly as you incrementally top it off.

Comment: A correctly operating car does not "use" any coolant..

Answer (score 1):

You are either leaking it or burning it.

Some leaks may occur at a hose, radiator, or the heater core.  The heater core leaking may cause your carpet inside the car to be wet.

If your radiator cap has failed, it will cause the overflow bottle to overflow, loosing coolant.

If you have a blown head gasket, cracked head, or cracked block, coolant can leak into your combustion chamber or into your oil.  Check your oil and under the oil cap.  If it looks like a milkshake, coolant has leaked into your oil.  Check your spark plugs.  If one looks oddly clean, that cylinder is burning coolant.